# silverlight process on client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, httprequest

i am a php developer, not knowing much about silverlight, i am working on a project which needs to process request on client browser, like post httprequests and process them, its a auto directory submitter, can it be done in silverlight application?

i want the user to open the silverlight application, which will submit the post request from client side, and also process for success and failure.

is it possible?

please guide me.

thank you

Answer (score 2):

When you run a silverlight application, you basically download a .xap file (with dlls inside). Those are executed on your machine. I'm no PHP expert but I seem to recall that PHP is executed server-side - so now you know the difference.

In order to communicate with the server you can use one of the popular methods :

- use a WCF Webservice
- use a WCF Ria WebService
- use a WCF REST Webservice
- use Sockets

I'm not sure but I think that using a WebClient object is also possible with a POST verb (you'd need to look it up though).

You can access silverlight.net's learning section for some good videos about using WCF services or hand-on labs. I'd also recommend Matthew McDonald's Pro Silverlight (3 or 4) books, those have some good socket examples.

Hope that helps.

Regards